# MVC Controller returning different views; Model data not being saved in hidden input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting a multiple page form where I use a single controller action and returning a view depending on a value on my model.

My model has a property that I put in an input field on my views, using Html.HiddenFor().

Here's my simplified model:

```
public class MyModel 
{
   public virtual int Step { get; set; }
}
```

And in my views, I have:

```
@model MyModel
...
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Step)
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ...
    myModel.Step = 1;
    return View("View1", myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel myModel)
{
    ...
    if (myModel.Step == 1)
    {
        myModel.Step = 2;
        return View("View2", myModel);
    }
    else if (myModel.Step == 2)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is, my controller always sees mymodel.Step as having the value of 1. Why is that?

What's weird is that I tried to display it on the form with these:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Step)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Step)
```

The second time the page was displayed, the first line showed the text "2". The second showed an input field with "1". I'm confused.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

My model also has a Guid property which is passed onto the View in a hidden field. I tried to change it also on postback, and check its value the second time around. The new value did not register. The model returned the original value before the first post. So it is consistent with the other field.

I may have to use different controller actions if I couldn't find why it is behaving the way it does at the moment.

**SOLUTION:**

As Reda suggested below, I fixed it by doing this in my post action method:

- Before displaying "View2" and to effect changes my controller makes to a value in my model, I run ModelState.Clear()

Here is a [blog post](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object) which confirms the need to clear ModelState for this scenario.

Comment: Are you sure that you land on correct action during navigation?

Comment: @Dima, yes. I was actually debugging it first on VS before I tried displaying the field as text and input field.

Comment: My model is a POCO, so I'm not sure showing the full class is relevant. Also, it has other classes as properties. Showing them all would create noise to this post, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when you return to view from your post action, it means that something failed during validation process and the form should be displayed again with the submitted values. That's why the `ModelState` remembers your inputs when you return to View, and your inputs will be filled from the `ModelState`, not your view model.

In my opinion you have two solutions :

- `ModelState.Clear`, which will erase your old value, before setting new ones
- redirecting to a GET action, with new values

Second solution is a better one, because you're not displaying the old form with validation errors, you're just showing a new view with different values.

Here's an example (of course you adapt it to your needs) :

```
public ActionResult Create(int? step)
{
    ...
    myModel.Step = step.HasValue ? step.Value : 1; // or whatever logic you need to apply
    return View("View1", myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel myModel)
{
    ...
    if (myModel.Step == 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { step = 2 });
    }
    else if (myModel.Step == 2)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Reda, thanks for your explanation. That's the answer. I like the ModelState.Clear() suggestion. That appears to be the easiest solution. What I ended up doing was create a new ViewModel, pass values, clear ModelState, and return the view with the new ViewModel. It worked. It saved me time re-doing it things.

Comment: Actually, I didn't need to create a new view, I just needed to clear ModelState when I need to progress to the next section of my form.